# Changing into the comparative sentence

Tags: grammaticality

> When there is little; many people want to buy.

Can I change this sentence as following sentence?

> The less there is; the more people want to buy .

Comment: You *can*, but note that unlike the original, your revised version is ambiguous. It *could* mean that a shortage on the supply side causes ***more people*** to want to buy something (same as the original). But it could also mean that (the same *number* of) people have an ***increased desire*** to buy whatever it is. Which may or may not be a significant difference in meaning, depending on your context and exactly what you want to say.

Answer (score 1):

> When there is less; many people want to buy

Is a reference to a phenomenon called [**The Rule of Scarcity**](http://westsidetoastmasters.com/resources/laws_persuasion/chap7.html)

Sometimes when there is **less** of something, it will **draw more attention** which will then raise it's value (**scarcity value**).

A prime example of this when there is a new release of an Apple device.  Huge queues will form since initial supplies may be limited.  Another example is tickets for a **sold out rock concert** which then get resold in a secondary market at **inflated prices**.

This phenomena is referenced by colloquialisms

> **The less there is, the more they want**
>   Always leave them wanting more

It can jokingly be referred to as **the bikini phenomenon**

> the less there is, the more attention it gets